# Converting AntD resizable table to using functional component

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, resizable

I am attempting to **convert class component** to **functional component** since my code is mainly based on functional components.

I know how to change the other more common stuffs like the state and functions but these two blocks of codes I'm not too sure how to convert. The resizable functionality are now not working for sure after my changes.

```
handleResize = index => (e, { size }) => {
    this.setState(({ columns }) => {
      const nextColumns = [...columns];
      nextColumns[index] = {
        ...nextColumns[index],
        width: size.width,
      };
      return { columns: nextColumns };
    });
  };

  render() {
    const columns = this.state.columns.map((col, index) => ({
      ...col,
      onHeaderCell: column => ({
        width: column.width,
        onResize: this.handleResize(index),
      }),
    }));

    return <Table bordered components={this.components} columns={columns} dataSource={this.data} />;
  }
}
```

**This is after my attempt to change the code. Appreciate any help!**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './AccountPortfolio.scss';
import HeaderTitle from '../../../components/HeaderTitle/HeaderTitle';
import Footer from '../../../components/Footer/Footer';
import Sidebar from '../../../components/Navigation/Sidebar/Sidebar';
import HeaderComponent from '../../../components/Navigation/HeaderComponent/HeaderComponent';
import { Layout, Table, Breadcrumb } from 'antd';
import { Resizable } from 'react-resizable';
// import 'react-resizable/css/styles.css';

const ResizableTitle = (props) => {
  const { onResize, width, ...restProps } = props;

  if (!width) {
    return <th {...restProps} />;
  }

  return (
    <Resizable
      width={width}
      height={0}
      handle={
        <span
          className="react-resizable-handle"
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
          }}
        />
      }
      onResize={onResize}
      draggableOpts={{ enableUserSelectHack: false }}
    >
      <th {...restProps} />
    </Resizable>
  );
};

const { Content } = Layout;
function AccountPortfolioPage(props) {
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
    {
      title: 'Date',
      dataIndex: 'date',
      width: 200,
    },
    {
      title: 'Amount',
      dataIndex: 'amount',
      width: 100,
      sorter: (a, b) => a.amount - b.amount,
    },
    {
      title: 'Type',
      dataIndex: 'type',
      width: 100,
    },
    {
      title: 'Note',
      dataIndex: 'note',
      width: 100,
    },
    {
      title: 'Action',
      key: 'action',
      render: () => <a>Delete</a>,
    },
  ]);

  const components = {
    header: {
      cell: ResizableTitle,
    },
  };

  const data = [
    {
      key: 0,
      date: '2018-02-11',
      amount: 120,
      type: 'income',
      note: 'transfer',
    },
    {
      key: 1,
      date: '2018-03-11',
      amount: 243,
      type: 'income',
      note: 'transfer',
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      date: '2018-04-11',
      amount: 98,
      type: 'income',
      note: 'transfer',
    },
  ];

  const handleResize = (index) => (e, { size }) => {
    setColumns(({ columns }) => {
      const nextColumns = [...columns];
      nextColumns[index] = {
        ...nextColumns[index],
        width: size.width,
      };
      return { columns: nextColumns };
    });
  };

  const columnsData = columns.map((col, index) => ({
    ...col,
    onHeaderCell: (column) => ({
      width: column.width,
      onResize: handleResize(index),
    }),
  }));

  return (
    <>
      <Layout className="antsidebar__layout">
        <Sidebar defaultSelectedKeys="Account Portfolio" />
        <Layout className="antsidebar__site-layout">
          <HeaderComponent />
          <Content style={{ margin: '0 16px' }}>
            <Breadcrumb style={{ margin: '16px 0' }}>
              <Breadcrumb.Item>MMS</Breadcrumb.Item>
              <Breadcrumb.Item>Account Portfolio</Breadcrumb.Item>
            </Breadcrumb>
            <div className="antsidebar__site-layout-background">
              <HeaderTitle headerText="Account Portfolio" />
              <Table bordered components={components} columns={columnsData} dataSource={data} />
            </div>
            <Footer />
          </Content>
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}

export default AccountPortfolioPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I dont know if this is the right way to do it, but somehow it's working now after I change the handle resize function to this

```
  const handleResize = (index) => (e, { size }) => {
    const nextColumns = [...columns];
    nextColumns[index] = {
      ...nextColumns[index],
      width: size.width,
    };

    setColumns(nextColumns);
  };
```

Let me know if there is a better way of fixing/improving them. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

in antd you can see the example code with functional component:
https://ant.design/components/table#components-table-demo-resizable-column

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'antd';
import { Resizable } from 'react-resizable';
const ResizableTitle = (props) => {
  const { onResize, width, ...restProps } = props;
  if (!width) {
    return <th {...restProps} />;
  }
  return (
    <Resizable
      width={width}
      height={0}
      handle={
        <span
          className="react-resizable-handle"
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
          }}
        />
      }
      onResize={onResize}
      draggableOpts={{
        enableUserSelectHack: false,
      }}
    >
      <th {...restProps} />
    </Resizable>
  );
};
const App = () => {
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
    {
      title: 'Date',
      dataIndex: 'date',
      width: 200,
    },
    {
      title: 'Amount',
      dataIndex: 'amount',
      width: 100,
      sorter: (a, b) => a.amount - b.amount,
    },
    {
      title: 'Type',
      dataIndex: 'type',
      width: 100,
    },
    {
      title: 'Note',
      dataIndex: 'note',
      width: 100,
    },
    {
      title: 'Action',
      key: 'action',
      render: () => <a>Delete</a>,
    },
  ]);
  const data = [
    {
      key: 0,
      date: '2018-02-11',
      amount: 120,
      type: 'income',
      note: 'transfer',
    },
    {
      key: 1,
      date: '2018-03-11',
      amount: 243,
      type: 'income',
      note: 'transfer',
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      date: '2018-04-11',
      amount: 98,
      type: 'income',
      note: 'transfer',
    },
  ];
  const handleResize =
    (index) =>
    (_, { size }) => {
      const newColumns = [...columns];
      newColumns[index] = {
        ...newColumns[index],
        width: size.width,
      };
      setColumns(newColumns);
    };
  const mergeColumns = columns.map((col, index) => ({
    ...col,
    onHeaderCell: (column) => ({
      width: column.width,
      onResize: handleResize(index),
    }),
  }));
  return (
    <Table
      bordered
      components={{
        header: {
          cell: ResizableTitle,
        },
      }}
      columns={mergeColumns}
      dataSource={data}
    />
  );
};
export default App;
```

css (it's important):

```
#components-table-demo-resizable-column .react-resizable {
  position: relative;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

#components-table-demo-resizable-column .react-resizable-handle {
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: col-resize;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35778872)